# Is there a way to tell if automapping is enabled for mailbox permissions in Office 365 via Powershell?

Tags: powershell, office365

I tried the PowerShell command below to extract a report for all Shared Mailboxes to our tenant. It was successful but it didn't provide the information I need. I would like to know as well if the automapping is set as "True" or "False" for each member of a Shared Mailbox. TIA!

```
Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox -ResultSize:Unlimited | Get-MailboxPermission | Select-Object Identity,User,AccessRights,IsInherited | Where-Object {($_.user -like '*@*')} | Export-Csv C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\xxxxx.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: That's quite a puzzle. You'll have to investigate the `msExchDelegateListLink` property of the shared mailbox to see which users itcontains. Perhaps you can use [this module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CPolydorou.Exchange/2.5.0/Content/Automapping.psm1) for that. The other way around should also be possible, by checking the Read-Only `msExchDelegateListBL` property on a user

Comment: Hi Theo, Thank you for taking the time to share your ideas. For msExchDelegateListLink & msExchDelegateListBL are these AD Attributes? Please correct me if I'm wrong if msExchDelegateListBL is present meaning his/her GMB automapping access is set to false? TIA.

Comment: Yes, these are AD attributes. The shared mailbox has a `msExchDelegateListLink`, filled with the DN's of the users and the user has a (hidden) attribute `msExchDelegateListBL` filled with DN's of the shared mailboxes.   
To view this in ADUC, you need to enable `Advanced Features` in the View menu.  
Whenever a user gets permissions on a shared box, the users DN is added to the `msExchDelegateListLink` property of the shared box and by default, the users `msExchDelegateListBL` attribute is populated with the DN of the shared mailbox.

Comment: To work out which mailboxes a user should **automap** you can look at the AD attribute `msExchDelegateListLinkBL` which will list the Distinguished Name of all mailboxes that are automapped by this user. If the DN of a shared mailbox is **not** present there, then for that user automapping to the shared box is turned **off**.

Comment: Ready-to-go code is about this is hard to find, but here two links that can help you further: [Copy Links and Backlinks Between Users and Shared Mailboxes (automapping)](https://c7solutions.com/2018/06/copy-links-and-backlinks-between-users-and-shared-mailboxes-automapping) and [Links and Backlinks in Active Directory for Exchange](https://neroblanco.co.uk/2015/07/links-and-backlinks-in-active-directory-for-exchange/)

Comment: Thank you Theo. I will surely try all your recommendation. It seems this Auto mapping check is like a connect the dot scenario.

Comment: Yes, it sure seems a lot of work to get this info. Sorry I can't help you any further on this, but for me there's no way to test. Please, if you find or create a workable solution, post it as answer. I'm sure others will be interested as well.

Comment: Theo - I was able to export msExchDelegateListLink AD properties of the Group Mailbox and you are correct. Those users are listed in that properties their GMB automapping access was set to "True". But I ran another problem, it only partially exports the msExchDelegateListLink properties and on the .CSV file there’s another column that appeared “Length” which was not listed on the PowerShell command that I’ve run. I think I need another set of eyes to look at the script that I have used, hoping you can identify the error I made. TIA!

Comment: Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Group Mailboxes,OU=Users and Groups,DC=XXXXXX,DC=net"-Properties msExchDelegateListLink,mail | Select-object -ExpandProperty msExchDelegateListLink @{name="msExchDelegateListLink";expression={$_.msExchDelegateListLink -join";"}},name,sAMAccountName,mail |export-csv -path C:\Users\XXXXXX\Downloads\XXXX.csv

Comment: Although hard to read in the comment, you at least need to add `-NoTypeInformation` to the Export-Csv cmdlet. I also think you should remove `-ExpandProperty msExchDelegateListLink`. Can you try?

Comment: Also, it is best to always enclose a path in quotes, in case there are spaces in there. P.S. The `Length` column you now have is the result of `-ExpandProperty msExchDelegateListLink`, which gives you an array which has a Count property. Just remove that from your code., you don't want to expand on just that single property.  If you finished the code, I encourage you to post it as answer to your own question.

Comment: Hi Theo - I did remove the -ExpandProperty msExchDelegateListLink and add -NoTypeInformation but the msExchDelegateListLink column in csv file becomes empty.

Comment: That's because you are using the wrong attribute here. For User objects (`Get-ADUser`), the attribute is called `msExchDelegateListBL` (BL stands for BackLink). The shared mailbox has an attribute called `msExchDelegateListLink`

Answer (score 0):

based on this sentence

There is a way for on-prem and for hybrid. Are you in a hybrid setup? If automapping is NOT being utilized by a user, the user who has access to the mailbox does not appear in the msExchDelegateListLink attribute on the shared mailbox AD user object. If automapping IS being utilized by a user, you'll see the user DN within the attribute. For onprem, its just this one attribute. There is a second attribute for hybrid called  msExchDelegateListBL.

i found this

Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox -ResultSize:Unlimited | % {get-aduser -identity $_.distinguishedname -properties msExchDelegateListLink, msExchDelegateListBL}

what do u think ? this command really works ?